# Error while running an emulator

Tags: linux, android-emulator, android-sdk, android-studio, ubuntu-one

=== About ===
Build version: Android Studio 3.6.2 Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6308749 March 19, 2020
Java version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211amd64
Operating System: Linux (5.4.0-31-generic, amd64)
JVM version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JetBrains s.r.o

Event Log :

```
31/5/20
7:37 AM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

7:37 AM * daemon started successfully

7:38 AM Gradle sync started

7:38 AM Gradle sync finished in 5 s 456 ms (from cached state)

7:38 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/adeshchoudhar/AndroidStudioProjects/HigherOrderFunctionalities

7:38 AM Emulator: E0531 07:38:29.247262716   10618 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1590890909.247245520","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

7:40 AM Gradle build finished in 1 m 52 s 648 ms

7:41 AM Install successfully finished in 37 s 891 ms.
```

I have 8GB ram, and I know the emulator is quite heavy to load, so it is slow. But it was working fine, however while working I messed up something and ended up in this error message.

```
7:38 AM Emulator: E0531 07:38:29.247262716   10618 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1590890909.247245520","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
```

The emulator is now also working fine. But sometimes, my system hangs. I have to wait for to everything run smoothly and also there is a problem in closing the emulator. My questions are:
**1. (top priority) How to resolve the above error / what is the reason / what is the meaning of the error?

2. Emulator hangs the system and does not get shut down or closed quickly, is this normal?

3. What does the size on the disk in the AVD manager means? Is it ram which is taken or just memory?

4. How to optimise the speed of emulator? How to properly use it from start to end?**

I know I'm asking more questions, but they are linked, as long as I think, so please contribute.
Any help would be appreciable, your contribution will help me a lot to learn.
Please comment and help me, if you know anything regarding my questions.

Comment: You must make sure to enable 'Virtualization' in your system in bios setup.

Comment: @AbdullahKhanNiazi It is enabled already. Can you help more?